# Can we deploy Apex Trigger Handler class from one sandbox to other without its Test Class in Copado?

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforcedx, deployment, cicd

I have modified, one single line in an Apex Trigger Handler and i need to deploy to another sandbox
without its test class, So may i please know how to deploy this in Copado?

Thanks,
Vidya

Answer (score 1):

In the general sense, you can deploy code to any org that is not a production org without deploying or running unit tests. However, as Copado is third-party software, it would be best to engage with their support team to find out the specific steps you'd need to take to deploy your code in this manner.